# GeoFire removeAllListeners() method not removing the listener at all

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have a geofire query that gets the nearby users. Everything is working fine but I want to stop listening to new events if the `pagingCounter` reaches certain limit. I have added `geoQuery.removeAllListeners()` in `onKeyEntered()` method but that is not removing the listener. The events are still getting and `onKeyEntered()` method keeps getting called until it reads all the elements in DB.

Please help me identify what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
var pagingCounter = 0
        val geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(GeoLocation(mainUserLatitude, mainUserLongitude), distanceInKm)

        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener {

            override fun onGeoQueryReady() {
                for ((key, value) in nearByUsersKeysTreeMap) {
                    val singleUserDatabaseReference = database.child(Constants.users).child(key)

                    singleUserDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                        }

                        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                        }
                    })
                }
            }

            override fun onKeyEntered(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {

                pagingCounter++

                if (pagingCounter >= 100) {
                    geoQuery.removeAllListeners()
                }
            }

            override fun onKeyMoved(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {
            }

            override fun onKeyExited(key: String?) {
            }

            override fun onGeoQueryError(error: DatabaseError?) {
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are all keys that are initially in range, then what you're seeing is the expected behavior. Retrieving all keys that are initially in range from the database is an operation that can't be interrupted.

Calling `removeAllListeners` prevents retrieving further updates to the keys from the database, but the client will still fire events for all listeners for which it has already received data.

If you want to no longer respond to those events, you can use a field that you set when you call `removeAllListeners` and then check for that field's value in the `onKey*` methods.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you so much for answering my question. Maybe i am approaching the problem in a wrong way. I am trying to acheive something like pagination. I will easily have more than 10,000 records in my firebase db within the specified radius. I really dont want to load all 10,000 records on my android device. I want to load around 2000 first, then the next set and so on. Can you please give some guidance on how I can acheive this? (I thought about starting with small radius and keep increasing it but that doesn’t solve my problem too)

Comment: The common approach is to start with a smaller range and gradually increase it, but since you rule that out too, there might not be a lot GeoFire can do for you here. You might want to watch this talk I did a few years ago to understand why this library (and others based on geohashes) are more limited than what you're looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q

Comment: Got it. Thank you